# How to automatically load the database name when launching an Oracle Forms 11g application?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

[image]

In fact, I want the user to fill in only the username and password without knowing what the name of the database is. I tried with the `formsweb.cfg` file and the env file but it doesn't work. Then I tried to find the login form without success.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify any configuration files; just create `ON-LOGON` trigger which calls the `LOGON` built-in. Provide null password and specify database name:

```
logon(null, '@my_db_name');
```

When you run the form, logon screen will wait for username and password, but database will already have its value.

---

[image]